# Angular6: Unable to access js variable in template getting async data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, razorpay

I am trying to print the list of banks given by razorpay on the template
I get all the bank lists Object in response and save it in a variable banks, but this variable does nothing in the template i.e. I can't see any value

I tried to print below code and I can never see Hello getting print

```
<h2 *ngIf="banks">Hello</h2>
```

Below is my snippet from component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.common.platformCheck()) {
      var razorpay = document.createElement('script');
      razorpay.id = 'razorPay'
      razorpay.src = 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js';
      razorpay.async = true;
      razorpay.type = "text/javascript";
      var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(razorpay, scpt);
      razorpay.onload = () => {
        var options = {
          "key": "rzp_test_XXXXXXXXXXX",
          "image": 'https://i.imgur.com/n5tjHFD.png'
        };
        var razorpay = this.windowObj.Razorpay(options);
         razorpay.once('ready', function (response) {
           this.banks= response.methods.netbanking;
          console.log(response.methods);
          console.log(razorpay.methods.netbanking);
          // response.methods.netbanking contains list of all banks
        })
      };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   razorpay.once('ready', function (response) {
       this.banks= response.methods.netbanking;
      console.log(response.methods);
      console.log(razorpay.methods.netbanking);
      // response.methods.netbanking contains list of all banks
    })
```

The issue is in the `function` keyword, since the `this` used inside that function block will be contextual to the function itself, not the component's `this`. Just change it to this:

```
   razorpay.once('ready', (response) => {
       this.banks= response.methods.netbanking;
      console.log(response.methods);
      console.log(razorpay.methods.netbanking);
      // response.methods.netbanking contains list of all banks
    })
```

and it should work, since the `this` will refer to the component's `this`, filling the correct component property.

More readings about ..."this":

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [How does "this" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)